# PowerShell WebServiceProxy with forms authentication

Tags: web-services, powershell, soap

I am working on building a few interfaces with Remedy 9.1 web services. It is configured with Forms authentication to get to the WSDL. I would like to keep it in that configuration so that the more powerful web services remain protected.

I have parts of a solution, but I am not sure that they can work together, perhaps you know of a solution?

This works if I remove forms auth:

```
function New-ObjectFromProxy {
param($proxy, $proxyAttributeName, $typeName)
# Locate the assembly for $proxy
$attribute = $proxy | gm | where { $_.Name -eq $proxyAttributeName }
$str = "`$assembly = [" + $attribute.TypeName + "].assembly"
invoke-expression $str
# Instantiate an AuthenticationHeaderValue object.
$type = $assembly.getTypes() | where { $_.Name -eq $typeName }

    return $assembly.CreateInstance($type)
}
$Now = get-date -Format G
$Q = "'System Broadcast End Date' >= """ + $Now +  """"

$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "https://mycompany-itsm.columncloud.com/arsys/WSDL/public/servername/CFG%3ABroadcast"
$authHeader = New-ObjectFromProxy -proxy $proxy -proxyAttributeName "AuthenticationInfoValue" -typeName "AuthenticationInfo"
$authHeader.userName = "username"
$authHeader.password = "password"
$proxy.AuthenticationInfoValue = $authHeader
$Response = $proxy.GetList($Q,"","") 
$Response | format-Table Broadcast_Start_Date, Broadcast_Message
```

However, if I move the webservice back behind the forms auth, I can get to the WSDL if I do this:

```
#this is the url that you want will send thae request to
$url = "https://mycompany-itsm.columncloud.com/arsys/servlet/LoginServlet"
#here you can set your POST params

$parameters = "username=username&pwd=ppaasswwoorrdd&encpwd=1&ipoverride=0&initialState=-1&timezone=-28800000&goto=/arsys/WSDL/protected/servername/HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WS"
#creating the xmlHtpp system object              
$http_request = New-Object -ComObject Msxml2.XMLHTTP
$http_request.open('POST', $url, $false)
#Setting required header of the request
$http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
$http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", $parameters.length)
#Assigning the params to the request
$Resp = $http_request.send($parameters)
echo $http_request.responseText
```

I would like to find a solution to combine these solutions together to use forms auth to get to the WSDL and create a webServiceProxy object. Perhaps my google-fu is weak, but I have not found a formsauth solution for new-webserviceProxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Origin code from POSHCODE site. updated to add formsauth

Basically I had to use the way back machine to figure out how this was done before it was made super simple by new-WebServiceProxy. I fire up a web request to post with forms auth data and grab the cookie for the conversation. If my cookie expires, I go get a new one (might explain my waistline).

Huge props to Oisin Grehan for publishing his code 7 years ago.

Call it like this:
.\New-WebServiceProxy-FormsAuth.ps1 -Url "https://mycompany/WSDL/public/servername/CFG%3ABroadcast" -Namespace "mystuff" -Cookies $CookieJar -lurl "https://mycompany/servlet/LoginServlet" -postData "username=username&pwd=ppaasswwoorrdd&encpwd=1&ipoverride=0&initialState=-1&timezone=-28800000"

```
# New-WebServiceProxy-FormsAuth.ps1 (v3.0 Sep 23, 2009)
#
# Oisin Grehan <oising@gmail.com> (x0n)
# ghangas
#
# Usage:
#   $proxy = .\New-WebServiceProxy.ps1 [-Url] http://site/service.asmx -lurl <http://site/loginpostpage> -postData <form data url encoded> [[-SoapProtocol] <Soap | Soap12>] [-Namespace <namespace>] [-Cookies <CookieContainer>] 
#
# to see available webmethods:
# $proxy | gm
#

param($url = $(throw "need `$url"), [string]$protocol = "Soap", [string]$Namespace="", [System.Net.CookieContainer]$CookieJar, [string]$lurl, [string]$postData)

[void][system.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("system.web.services")

trap {
        "Error:`n`n $error";
        break;
}

#$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url);
$dcp = new-object system.web.services.discovery.discoveryclientprotocol

if ($CookieJar -ne $null) {
    If ($CookieJar.ToString() = "System.Net.CookieContainer") {
        $dcp.CookieContainer = $CookieJar
    }
}

Write-Progress "Discovery" "Searching..."
$dcp.AllowAutoRedirect = $true


try {[void]$dcp.DiscoverAny($url)
}
catch {
$CookieJar = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer

$buffer = [text.encoding]::ascii.getbytes($postData)

[net.httpWebRequest] $req = [net.webRequest]::create($lurl)
$req.method = "POST"
$req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
$req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US")
$req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate")
$req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7")
$req.AllowAutoRedirect = $true
$req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0"
$req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
$req.ContentLength = $buffer.length
$req.TimeOut = 50000
$req.KeepAlive = $true
$req.CookieContainer = $CookieJar
$reqst = $req.getRequestStream()
$reqst.write($buffer, 0, $buffer.length)
$reqst.flush()
$reqst.close()
[net.httpWebResponse] $res = $req.getResponse()
$dcp.CookieContainer = $CookieJar
[void]$dcp.DiscoverAny($url)
}

$dcp.ResolveAll()
# get service name
foreach ($entry in $dcp.Documents.GetEnumerator()) { # needed for Dictionary
    if ($entry.Value -is [System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription]) {
        $script:serviceName = $entry.Value.Services[0].Name
        Write-Verbose "Service: $serviceName"
    }
}

Write-Progress "WS-I Basic Profile 1.1" "Validating..."
$ns = new-Object System.CodeDom.CodeNamespace $Namespace

$wref = new-object System.Web.Services.Description.WebReference $dcp.Documents, $ns
$wrefs = new-object system.web.services.description.webreferencecollection
[void]$wrefs.Add($wref)

$ccUnit = new-object System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit
[void]$ccUnit.Namespaces.Add($ns)

$violations = new-object system.web.Services.Description.BasicProfileViolationCollection
$wsi11 = [system.web.services.WsiProfiles]::BasicProfile1_1

if ([system.web.Services.Description.WebServicesInteroperability]::CheckConformance($wsi11, $wref, $violations)) {
    Write-Progress "Proxy Generation" "Compiling..."

    $webRefOpts = new-object System.Web.Services.Description.WebReferenceOptions
        $webRefOpts.CodeGenerationOptions = "GenerateNewAsync","GenerateProperties" #,"GenerateOldAsync"

        #StringCollection strings = ServiceDescriptionImporter.GenerateWebReferences(
        #       webReferences, codeProvider, codeCompileUnit, parameters.GetWebReferenceOptions());

    $csprovider = new-object Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider
        $warnings = [System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionImporter]::GenerateWebReferences(
                $wrefs, $csprovider, $ccunit, $webRefOpts)

    if ($warnings.Count -eq 0) {
        $param = new-object system.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
        [void]$param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll")
        [void]$param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Web.Services.dll")        
        $param.GenerateInMemory = $true;
        #$param.TempFiles = (new-object System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection "c:\temp", $true)
        $param.GenerateExecutable = $false;
        #$param.OutputAssembly = "$($ns.Name)_$($sdname).dll"
        $param.TreatWarningsAsErrors = $false;
        $param.WarningLevel = 4;

        # do it
        $compileResults = $csprovider.CompileAssemblyFromDom($param, $ccUnit);

        if ($compileResults.Errors.Count -gt 0) {
            Write-Progress "Proxy Generation" "Failed."
            foreach ($output in $compileResults.Output) { write-host $output }
            foreach ($err in $compileResults.Errors) { write-warning $err }            
        } else {            
            $assembly = $compileResults.CompiledAssembly

            if ($assembly) {
                if ($namespace) {
                        $serviceType = $assembly.GetType($namespace + "." + $serviceName)
                } else {
                  $serviceType = $assembly.GetType($serviceName)
                }
                $assembly.GetTypes() | % { Write-Verbose $_.FullName }
            } else {
                Write-Warning "Failed: `$assembly is null"
                                return
            }

            # return proxy instance
            $proxy = new-object $serviceType.FullName
            $proxy # dump instance to pipeline
        }
    } else {
        Write-Progress "Proxy Generation" "Failed."        
        Write-Warning $warnings
    }
    #Write-Progress -Completed
}
```